# ¿Por qué no funciona el "getline()"?

Tags: c++, funciones

Estaba practicando el uso de las clases y objetos y quise hacer algo sencillo, tuve algunos problemas, pero he logrado solucionarlos. Hubo uno en particular que no: la función `getline()`. La parte que no me funciona es ésta:

```
void agregar(void) {
string entarNombre;
string entrarEnfermedad;
int entrarEdad;
float entrarPeso;
gotoxy(1,1);cout << "Ingresa el nombre de tu mascota: ";
gotoxy(1,2);cin >> entarNombre;
gotoxy(1,3);cout << "Ingresa la edad de tu mascota: ";
gotoxy(1,4);cin >> entrarEdad;
gotoxy(1,5);cout << "Ingresa el peso de tu mascota: ";
gotoxy(1,6);cin >> entrarPeso;
gotoxy(1,7);cout << "Tiene alguna enfermedad? ";
gotoxy(1,8);getline(cin, entrarEnfermedad);
```

El problema empieza en esta última línea. ¿Por qué no funciona? Simplemente se salta esa instrucción.

El código completo es éste:

(Por cierto, la `clase.hpp` es una clase creada por mi, pero no creo que ese sea el problema, en esa misma clase se encuentra "iostream" por eso no lo agregué en el archivo principal).

```
#include "clase.hpp"
#include "conio.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "cstring"
#include "cstdlib"

void gotoxy (int x, int y) {
    HANDLE consola;
    consola = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD coordenadas;
    coordenadas.X = x;
    coordenadas.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(consola,coordenadas);
}

using namespace std;
//Prototipos de funciones.
void bienvenida (void);
void buscar (void);
void agregar (void);

//Variables globales.
bool programa = 1;
bool bienv = 1;
bool busc = 0;
bool agreg = 0;
int contDeRegistros = 0;
int edad;
float peso;
//string nombre;
string enfermedad;

//objetos globales.
    Perro uno;
    Perro dos;
    Perro tres;
    Perro cuatro;

// Main.
int main(void){
    //Variables.


    //Programa.
    while (programa == 1) {
        while (bienv == 1) {
            bienvenida();
        }
        while (busc == 1) {
            buscar();
        }
        while (agreg == 1) {
            agregar();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
//-------------------------------FUNCIONES--------------------------------
void bienvenida (void) {
    string entrada;
    gotoxy(1,1);cout << "Buscar una mascota (buscar) o agregar una (agregar).";
    gotoxy(1,2);cin >> entrada;
    if (entrada == "buscar" || entrada == "Buscar" || entrada == "BUSCAR") {
        busc = 1;
        agreg = 0;
        bienv = 0;
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                                   ";
        gotoxy(1,2);cout << "                                                                  ";
    }
    else if (entrada == "agregar" || entrada == "Agregar" || entrada == "AGREGAR") {
        agreg = 1;
        bienv = 0;
        busc = 0;
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,2);cout << "                                                                      ";
    }
    else if (entrada == "salir" || entrada == "Salir" || entrada == "SALIR") {
        bienv = 0;
        programa = 0;
    }
    else {
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                                        ";
        gotoxy(1,2);cout << "                                                                         ";
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "No es un comando valido...";
        getch();
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                                          ";
    }
}
void buscar(void) {
    string entrada;
    gotoxy(1,1);cout << "Escribe el nombre de la mascota: ";
    gotoxy(1,2);cin >> entrada;
    if (entrada == uno.nombre){
        edad = uno.obtenerEdad();
        peso = uno.obtenerPeso();
        enfermedad = uno.obtenerEnfermedad();
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,2);cout << "                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "Nombre: " << uno.nombre << endl;
        gotoxy(1,2);cout << "Edad: " << edad << " anios" << endl;
        gotoxy(1,3);cout << "Peso: " << peso << " kilos" << endl;
        gotoxy(1,4);cout << "Enfermedad: " << enfermedad << endl;
        getch();
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,2);cout << "                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,3);cout << "                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,4);cout << "                                                      ";

    }
    else if (entrada == dos.nombre){
        edad = dos.obtenerEdad();
        peso = dos.obtenerPeso();
        enfermedad = dos.obtenerEnfermedad();
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,2);cout << "                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "Nombre: " << dos.nombre << endl;
        gotoxy(1,2);cout << "Edad: " << edad << " anios" << endl;
        gotoxy(1,3);cout << "Peso: " << peso << " kilos" << endl;
        gotoxy(1,4);cout << "Enfermedad" << enfermedad << endl;
        getch();
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,2);cout << "                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,3);cout << "                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,4);cout << "                                                      ";

    }
    else if (entrada == tres.nombre){
        edad = tres.obtenerEdad();
        peso = tres.obtenerPeso();
        enfermedad = tres.obtenerEnfermedad();
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,2);cout << "                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "Nombre: " << tres.nombre << endl;
        gotoxy(1,2);cout << "Edad: " << edad << " anios" << endl;
        gotoxy(1,3);cout << "Peso: " << peso << " kilos" << endl;
        gotoxy(1,4);cout << "Enfermedad" << enfermedad << endl;
        getch();
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,2);cout << "                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,3);cout << "                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,4);cout << "                                                      ";

    }
    else if (entrada == cuatro.nombre){
        edad = cuatro.obtenerEdad();
        peso = cuatro.obtenerPeso();
        enfermedad = cuatro.obtenerEnfermedad();
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,2);cout << "                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "Nombre: " << cuatro.nombre << endl;
        gotoxy(1,2);cout << "Edad: " << edad << " anios" << endl;
        gotoxy(1,3);cout << "Peso: " << peso << " kilos" << endl;
        gotoxy(1,4);cout << "Enfermedad" << enfermedad << endl;
        getch();
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,2);cout << "                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,3);cout << "                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,4);cout << "                                                      ";

    }
    else {
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,2);cout << "                                                      ";
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "No esta registrado, registralo para tener sus datos. :D";
        getch();
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                        ";

    }
    busc = 0;
    bienv = 1;
    agreg = 0;
}
void agregar(void) {
    string entarNombre;
    string entrarEnfermedad;
    int entrarEdad;
    float entrarPeso;
    gotoxy(1,1);cout << "Ingresa el nombre de tu mascota: ";
    gotoxy(1,2);cin >> entarNombre;
    gotoxy(1,3);cout << "Ingresa la edad de tu mascota: ";
    gotoxy(1,4);cin >> entrarEdad;
    gotoxy(1,5);cout << "Ingresa el peso de tu mascota: ";
    gotoxy(1,6);cin >> entrarPeso;
    gotoxy(1,7);cout << "Tiene alguna enfermedad? ";
    gotoxy(1,8);getline(cin, entrarEnfermedad);
    if (contDeRegistros == 0) {
        uno.nombre = entarNombre;
        uno.configurarEdad(entrarEdad);
        uno.configurarPeso(entrarPeso);
        uno.configurarEnfermedad(entrarEnfermedad);
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,2);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,3);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,4);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,5);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,6);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,7);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,8);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "Ya hemos registrado a tu mascota. Buscala en la base de datos! :D";
        getch();
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                                   ";

    }
    else if (contDeRegistros == 1) {
        dos.nombre = entarNombre;
        dos.configurarEdad(entrarEdad);
        dos.configurarPeso(entrarPeso);
        dos.configurarEnfermedad(entrarEnfermedad);
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,2);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,3);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,4);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,5);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,6);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,7);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,8);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "Ya hemos registrado a tu mascota. Buscala en la base de datos! :D";
        getch();
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                                   ";

    }
    else if (contDeRegistros == 2) {
        tres.nombre = entarNombre;
        tres.configurarEdad(entrarEdad);
        tres.configurarPeso(entrarPeso);
        tres.configurarEnfermedad(entrarEnfermedad);
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,2);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,3);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,4);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,5);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,6);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,7);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,8);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "Ya hemos registrado a tu mascota. Buscala en la base de datos! :D";
        getch();
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                                   ";

    }
    else if (contDeRegistros == 3) {
        cuatro.nombre = entarNombre;
        cuatro.configurarEdad(entrarEdad);
        cuatro.configurarPeso(entrarPeso);
        cuatro.configurarEnfermedad(entrarEnfermedad);
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,2);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,3);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,4);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,5);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,6);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,7);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,8);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "Ya hemos registrado a tu mascota. Buscala en la base de datos! :D";
        getch();
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                                   ";

    }
    else {
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,2);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,3);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,4);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,5);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,6);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,7);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,8);cout << "                                                               ";
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "Ya no hay espacio, lo siento...  :/";
        getch();
        gotoxy(1,1);cout << "                                                               ";

    }
    ++contDeRegistros;
    agreg = 0;
    bienv = 1;
    busc = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Requiere varias correcciones ..

- getline() y otros usos requieren poner espacio de nombres :

  ```
  using namespace std;
  ```
- getline() requiere usar su sintaxis, su declaración es :

  ```
  istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n );
  istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );
  ```
- getline() requiere ser precedido de ignore (cin) para detenerse a la espera
  de una entrada por teclado cuando no se especifica `char delim` :

  ```
  cin.ignore();
  ```
- Para usar getline() se requiere ponerlo tras el objeto del cual es miembro (cin) y el correspondiente punto :

  ```
  cin.getline(entrarEnfermedad,64);
  ```
- En C++, de modo nativo, no existe el tipo string, en cambio se usan arrays de caracteres (y punteros a caracteres). *Nota : Un array de caracteres sin corchetes ni indice, devuelve la dirección del primer caracter; El final de una cadena se determina por un catacter '\0'.* .. Por ello se han de declarar a modo de variables para cadenas de caracteres, arrays de tipo char :

  ```
  char entarNombre[64] = "";
  ```

*Sugiero este código (comprobado) :*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

 void gotoxy(int x,int y)
      {  
      HANDLE hcon;  
      hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);  
      COORD dwPos;  
      dwPos.X = x;  
      dwPos.Y= y;  
      SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon,dwPos);  
      }  


int main(int argc, char** argv)
     {
     using namespace std;

     char entarNombre[64] = "";
     char entrarEnfermedad[64] = "";
     int entrarEdad = 0;
     float entrarPeso = 0 ;

     gotoxy(1,1);
     cout << "Ingresa el nombre de tu mascota: ";
     gotoxy(1,2);
     cin >> entarNombre;
     gotoxy(1,3);
     cout << "Ingresa la edad de tu mascota: ";
     gotoxy(1,4);
     cin >> entrarEdad;
     gotoxy(1,5);
     cout << "Ingresa el peso de tu mascota: ";
     gotoxy(1,6);
     cin >> entrarPeso;
     gotoxy(1,7);
     cout << "Tiene alguna enfermedad? ";
     cin.ignore();
     gotoxy(1,8);
     cin.getline(entrarEnfermedad,64);  // Tamaño de buffer 64

     return 0;
     }
```

Comment: Es más útil cuando a parte de publicar las correcciones, explicas en qué consisten éstas y en qué se estaba equivocando el autor de la pregunta. Tal y como está la respuesta ahora mismo ayuda, pero muy poco.

Comment: Aclaración: "En C++ no existe el tipo string"... SÍ existe el tipo string (`std::string`), no es un tipo _nativo_ sino que precisa del fichero de cabecera _<string>_ pero existe. Internamente trabaja como un vector de caracteres.

Answer (score 1):

```
gotoxy(1,6);cin >> entrarPeso;
gotoxy(1,7);cout << "Tiene alguna enfermedad? ";
gotoxy(1,8);getline(cin, entrarEnfermedad);
```

> "¿Por qué no funciona? Simplemente se salta esa instrucción."

Bueno, en realidad sí funciona, y parece que se saltara esa instrucción, aunque en realidad sí la está ejecutando, sólo que el resultado no es el esperado.

Lo que ocurre es que cuando se ejecuta el último cin, en el buffer de entrada queda el último '\n' (nueva línea) que has pulsado, y luego getline() lee y descarta ese último '\n', dejando en entrarEnfermedad una cadena vacía, y ya no queda nadie para leer le nombre de la enfermedad que hayas escrito.

Entonces, hay que tener en cuenta el comportamiento de cin, que lee hasta el carácter de nueva línea pero no lo "consume", no lo quita del buffer de entrada; y el comportamiento de getline(), que cuando se encuentra con un '\n' lo ignora y detiene la lectura.

Como te comentaban en una respuesta anterior, existe la función [ignore()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) que va a leer y descartar los caracteres del flujo de entrada incluido el '\n' (o el delimitador que se establezca).

Por ejemplo:

```
gotoxy(1,6);cin >> entrarPeso;
cin.ignore(); // descarta el último '\n' 
gotoxy(1,7);cout << "Tiene alguna enfermedad? ";
gotoxy(1,8);getline(cin, entrarEnfermedad);
getline(cin, str);
```

va a funcionar.