# Ayuda con función cin.getline C++

Tags: c++, string

Saludos.

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código de C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main () {

    int n;

    cout << "Ingrese la cantidad de valores a procesar: ";
    cin >> n;

    char nombre[n][500];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Escriba el nombre: ";
        cin.getline(nombre[i], 500);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        cout << "\nEl valor ingresado es: " << nombre[j];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Cuando le doy un valor fijo al subíndice del arreglo de cadenas, no tengo problema para ingresar y mostrar los nombres al programa; pero cuando no especifico el valor y lo tomo de la variable "n", el ciclo FOR solamente me muestra la salida "Escriba el nombre" e inmediatamente se sale del ciclo.

¿Alguien sabe a que se debe?

Gracias!

Comment: Hay una pregunta casi idéntica en [¿Por qué no funciona el “getline()”?] (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/17306/por-qu%c3%a9-no-funciona-el-getline)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta agregando esta línea luego de leer `n`:

```
cin >> n;
cin.ignore();
```

Esto es por la manera que trabajan `cin >>` y `cin.getline`.

Cuando asignas un valor de esa manera, en la entrada también se queda pendiente (*buffer*) el caracter de cambio de línea <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

La función `cin.getline` lee la entrada hasta que se encuentra con el caracter de cambio de línea (por defecto), pero a diferencia de `cin >>` no lo deja en la entrada.

Entonces lo que ocurre en tu código es que cuando es el turno de ejecutar `cin.getline` la primera vez, lo que encuentra es un cambio de línea e ingresa un nombre en blanco.

`cin.ignore()` indica a la entrada que descarte lo que tenga pendiente, así no hay conflicto.

Comment: Gracias @Esquiso, el código ahora funciona además de que me dejaste claro lo del buffer.

Answer (score 3):

```
int cantidadDeCadenas = 0;

cout << "Indique la cantidad de lineas de entrada" << endl;
cin >> cantidadDeCadenas;
```

/*->>>> aqui esta la magia que compartio */    cin.ignore();

```
vector<string> datos;

for (int i = 0; i < cantidadDeCadenas; i++) {

    cout << "Introdusca la linea " << i << ": " << endl;
    string lineaCadena;

    getline(cin, lineaCadena);

    datos.push_back(lineaCadena);

}
```

//con esto leemos N lineas SALUDOS Y MUCHAS GRACIAS POR LA AYUDA